# Programmatically changing Locale to affect Google's Place Autocomplete service (Google Places API for Android)

Tags: android, localization, locale, google-places-api, google-places

Is there a way to programmatically change the `Locale` in a way that will **affect** Google's Place Autocomplete service?

---

I'll describe my situatuion:

I use a device with an **English** `Locale`. As expected, When I use **Hebrew** to search the Place Autocomplete service, it presents the possible results in **Hebrew** in a **LTR orientation**, and when I press a result and pull the data from the `Place` object in the `onPlaceSelected()` method, the returned information is in **English**.

[This is how it looks when I run the app and press the chosen location](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rGCe6.png)

This is the code for using the Place Autocomplete service:

```
PlaceAutocompleteFragment placeAutocompleteFragment = (PlaceAutocompleteFragment)
    getFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.place_autocomplete_fragment);

placeAutocompleteFragment.setOnPlaceSelectedListener(new PlaceSelectionListener() {
    @Override
    public void onPlaceSelected(Place place) {
        nameString = place.getName().toString();
        addressString = place.getAddress().toString();
        phoneNumberString = place.getPhoneNumber().toString();
        LatLng latLng = place.getLatLng();
        latitudeDouble = latLng.latitude;
        longitudeDouble = latLng.longitude;

        nameEditText.setText(nameString);
        addressEditText.setText(addressString);
        phoneNumberText.setText(phoneNumberString);
        latitudeTextView.setText(latitudeDouble.toString());
        longitudeTextView.setText(longitudeDouble.toString());
    }

    @Override
    public void onError(Status status) {
        // TODO: Handle the error.
        Log.i(TAG, "ERROR MESSAGE: " + status);
    }
});
```

The problem is that it still doesn't work, even though I **successfully** changed the `Locale` in the `Activity` programmatically via:

```
Locale locale = new Locale("iw");
Locale.setDefault(locale);
super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
...
```

Is there a way to solve this?

Comment: The Place details result should be requested using the locale of the device. Are you using an English locale with a Hebrew keyboard?

Comment: you're right, I've updated my question. tried changing the locale programmaticaly, but even though I did it successfully, it doesn't affect google's Place Autocomplete service... :/

Comment: It looks like the Place details is fetched using the Locale of the device, not that of the app. Maybe file a feature request at https://code.google.com/p/gmaps-api-issues/issues/list?can=2&q=apitype:AndroidPlaces&colspec=ID+Type+Status+Introduced+Fixed+Summary+Internal+Stars&cells=tiles

Comment: Thanks @AndrewR !